# The DATEDIFF function return 2 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct, datediff

I have the query that works properly and i get the following output :

```
9   1116    JOHN    0590056093  9106809105      3   A       NULL    D
9   1117    SARA    0015562451  9203410410      3   A       NULL    D
9   1118    DAVID   5560101753  9375115360      3   B       NULL    D
```

After adding the `datediff` column my output is as follows

```
9   1116    JOHN    0590056093  9106809105      3   A       NULL    D    10
9   1116    JOHN    0590056093  9106809105      3   A       NULL    D    1
9   1117    SARA    0015562451  9203410410      3   A       NULL    D    10
9   1117    SARA    0015562451  9203410410      3   A       NULL    D    1
9   1118    DAVID   5560101753  9375115360      3   B       NULL    D    10
9   1118    DAVID   5560101753  9375115360      3   B       NULL    D    1
```

What is the reason for displaying the 1 in the `datediff` column?

Query :

```
select distinct t1.*, fs.Name+' '+ed.Academic as takhasos, Articles.Title, MT.Name as paye,
datediff(m,Projects.StartDateProject, Projects.EndDateProject) as datedif 
from 
(select RC.ID, RCU.UserID, u.Name + ' ' + u.Family AS NameFamily, u.UserName, u.Mobile, u.Email, groupED.IdMaghtae
    from ResearchersCores AS RC LEFT OUTER JOIN
ResearchersCoreUsers AS RCU ON RC.ID = RCU.ResearchersCoreID LEFT OUTER JOIN
Users AS u ON u.Id = RCU.UserID LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT Eductionals.UserID , Max(Eductionals.MaghtaeID) AS IdMaghtae
    FROM Eductionals
    GROUP BY Eductionals.UserID) groupED
    ON u.Id = groupED.UserID 
WHERE        (RC.IsEnable = 1) AND (RCU.isEnable = 1) AND (RCU.RoleID = 5) ) t1 left outer join
Eductionals as ED ON ED.UserID = t1.UserID AND t1.IdMaghtae = ed.MaghtaeID left outer join
FieldStudies as FS ON ed.FieldStudy_ID = FS.ID left outer join
Articles ON Articles.UserID = t1.UserID left outer join
Projects ON Projects.RecordID = t1.ID and Projects.ControllerID = 8 left outer join
MaghtaeTahsilis MT On MT.ID = t1.IdMaghtae
where t1.id = 9
```

I want the following output

```
9   1116    JOHN    0590056093  9106809105      3   A       NULL    D    10
9   1117    SARA    0015562451  9203410410      3   A       NULL    D    10
9   1118    DAVID   5560101753  9375115360      3   B       NULL    D    10
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query uses `distinct` to remove duplicate rows. But the expression that you are adding has different values over these otherwise duplicate rows, so they are now showing in the resultset.

One option would be to use `group by` instead, and take the `max()` of datediff. This *requires* you to repeat all other columns in the `select` clause in the `group by` clause as well:

```
select 
    t1.col1,
    t1.col2,
    ..., 
    max(datediff(m,Projects.StartDateProject, Projects.EndDateProject)) as datedif 
from ...
where t1.id = 9
group by t1.col1, t1.col2, ...
```